# NSXMLParser crashes in iOS8

Tags: xml, crash, ios8, base64, nsxmlparser

Here is the code fragment of my iOS application:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {

[super viewDidLoad];
NSURL *xmlURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.example.com/image.xml"];
xmlParser = [[NSXMLParser alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:xmlURL];
[xmlParser setDelegate:self];
[xmlParser parse];
[self loadData];

}


- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didStartElement:(NSString *)elementName
  namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName
    attributes:(NSDictionary *)attributeDict{
    currentElement = [elementName copy];

    if ([currentElement isEqualToString:@"food"]) {
        [self saveData:[attributeDict objectForKey:@"att"]];  
    }

}

- (void)parserDidStartDocument:(NSXMLParser *)parser {
    NSLog(@"Start XML");
}

- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser parseErrorOccurred:(NSError *)parseError {
    NSLog(@"XML ERRROR");
}


- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didEndElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName{
    NSLog(@"[%@] Emlement Finish", elementName);
}

- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser foundCharacters:(NSString *)string{
    NSLog(@"[%@]Element Found", string);
}

- (void)parserDidEndDocument:(NSXMLParser *)parser {
    NSLog(@"XML Finish");
}
```

The program crashes at [xmlParser parse] in iOS8, but not in iOS7. Log showed "Start XML" only and program crashed afterwards.

The XML source is generated by another Java server program, which contains a Base64 encoded image in XML. XMLParser will not crash if the XML is at the size of 300KB or smaller.

I have also tried all the XMLParser solutions on StackOverflow, but in vain.

Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: facing this problem too  :(